# configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required with support for https at HPC

Tags: curl, libraries, cluster, r, header-file

I met an issue when I tried to configure for R installation in HPC. I'm trying to install R-4.1.0 and 4.3.0; both show similar issue.

> configure: error: libcurl >= 7.28.0 library and headers are required
> with support for https

As I'm working on HPC, thus don't have root privilege.
Any suggestions to overcome this issue would be greatly admired.

Thanks,
Deb